# Change cell value (text) based on date with conditinal formatting in Google Sheets?

Tags: date, google-apps-script, google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I have question. We are making a planning tool for one of our internal products. In this tool we can switch the status of an item (in this case a package) manually (drop down menu)(column E). Based on the status it is ending up in one of the employees planning overview tabs. But, every packages has an offline date (column G). This date is the moment that the package will go offline automatically. Based on the offline date I would like to switch the cell status automatically to 'Offline'. The problem is that this cell could also be changed manually (for other status).

I was thinking, may be there is a trick with conditional formatting to also change the value / text inside a cell. When the present date is the 'offline date' or later than the offline date the conditinal formatting will change the status of the cell to: "Offline".

Does anyone have a trick for this? Thank you in advance!

Link to example sheet: [Stackoverflow example date changes cell sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1a6eqV3mZ7m55JEFJo7TNHYhe_kT2YPq4BcLIma23fIQ/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: I think I get the idea but I think the best way would be using script to do the automatic change. Idea is that, status will be automatically changed once date reaches offline date. The issue is that it can only be changed automatically to offline once. When it is updated manually after it was automatically updated to offline, then you need to manually update it again to offline since the script would only automatically change the status when the date is equal to the offline date, would that be fine? If so then please do tell so I can provide a script with that behavior.

Comment: Note that the behavior I stated above can be run either by modifying offline date column or run daily during a specific time (e.g. 12am daily, etc.) I don't think conditional formatting can change a cell's value.

Comment: Hi @NaziA, that's correct. That's exactly what I'm looking for. I was thinking about a script later as well but something with onChange / onEdit will not work offcourse since the date is already there. I couldn't think of a right script. Would be great if you can help me here!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function does change the status in column E to 'Offline' if its accompanying offline date in column G is equal to the date the function is running.

#### Script:

```
function changeStatusToOffline() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();

  // column E for status
  var statusRange = sheet.getRange(2, 5, lastRow - 1, 1);
  var statusValues = statusRange.getValues();
  // column G for offline dates
  var offlineDateRange = sheet.getRange(2, 7, lastRow - 1, 1);
  var offlineDateValues = offlineDateRange.getValues();

  // set time properties of today to 0 to compare date values only
  // do the same with the individual offline dates later
  var todayDate = new Date();
  todayDate.setHours(0,0,0,0);
  var todayTime = todayDate.getTime();

  // generate status output during iteration of date values
  var statusOutput = offlineDateValues.map((offlineDateValue, index) => {
    // the same with today's date
    var offlineDate = new Date(offlineDateValue);
    offlineDate.setHours(0,0,0,0)
    var offlineTime = offlineDate.getTime();

    // if trigger date value is same as offline date value, change status to offline
    if (todayTime == offlineTime) 
      return ['Offline'];
    // use existing value if date are not the same
    return statusValues[index];
  });

  // set the status range by bulk 
  statusRange.setValues(statusOutput);
}
```

#### Note:

- Test the script by running it manually
- If it successfully does what you need, then proceed on setting up a daily trigger and trigger the function above daily on a specific time. (e.g. Daily 12AM)
- This only updates the status IF trigger date is equal to offline date. (This makes the trigger change the status change to offline just once)
- Only if you change the offline date to a later date, then it will be possible to automatically update the status when the script runs on that date again.

#### Before:

[image: before]

#### After:

[image: after]

Comment: Really cool, it works perfectly. This is a cool script since it is usable in many different ways. Thanks a lot!